# SharePoint 2010 designer workflow stuck at "Starting" status

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created approval designer workflow on a sharepoint document library.  The workflow runs when the item is created or updated.  It was working for fine until last month.. Suddenly it stopped working and status is showing as "Starting".  I have to terminate the workflows.  When i start manually it is working fine.. Why this is happening ? Is anyone having same issues ?  Please assist me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue, my workflow after start stuck on Starting mode and I have to terminate it. I found http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5a6e6e83-b59f-4099-a86f-a07723ff2b98/workflow-stuck-in-starting-state-after-applying-sharepoint-2010-cu-december-2012?forum=sharepointadminprevious I installed Update July 2013 but nothing chanage ...

It seems to me that it happend after installed Service Pack 2.

Thanks for help,

Comment: Yes, it seems the CU issue.  We resolved this by installing SP CU.

Comment: Which exactly CU did you install?

Comment: You can install June 2013 or later.